# LEFT JOIN with WHERE (Microsoft Access SQL)

Tags: join, ms-access, where

Given following 2 tables a, b:

#### table a

```
ID job
1  farmer
2  physician
3  bank clerk
```

#### table b

```
bID ID lang job
1   1  en   farmer
2   2  en   physician
3   3  en   bank clerk
4   2  de   Arzt
5   1  fr   paysan
```

#### Query

```
SELECT a.ID, a.job, b.job FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID=b.ID WHERE b.lang='de'
```

#### wanted:

```
a.ID a.job        b.job
1    farmer       -
2    physician    Arzt
3    bank clerk   -
```

#### actual result:

```
2    physician    Arzt
```

What's wrong with the `LEFT JOIN`? Do I need some (())?

Comment: Left join tries to add NULL-valued parts for right table when corresponding record(s) not exists... but then your condition in WHERE ejects all of them. And LEFT JOIN acts as INNER JOIN (with a lot of additional work). Remember - if you want any condition for right table, it is to be placed into ON section.

Answer (score 7):

In your query left join is performed only using only the condition `a.ID=b.ID` and then results are filtered based on condition `b.lang='de'`. You need to add both conditions on the left join:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.job, b.job 
FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
ON (a.ID=b.ID and b.lang='de')
```

Comment: For Access SQL, the composite ON condition must be within parenthesis like `ON (a.ID=b.ID and b.lang='de')`

Comment: That works great in T-SQL or probably any other flavour of SQL, but I get "JOIN expression not supported" whenever I try to use a literal in the ON condition in Microsoft Access.  It doesn't appear to be supported by Access SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/perform-joins-using-access-sql

Answer (score 2):

Here create an alias of specific language table as **c**.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.job, c.job FROM a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM b WHERE lang='de') as c
ON a.ID=c.ID
```

Comment: This solutions works perfectly in Microsoft Access.  Thanks!